# How does Redux Thunk implement

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm using Redux Thunk for my react app and I feel impressive how thunk work. For example:

```
export const doubleAsync = () => {
  // Thunk will automatically inject "dispatch" object here
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({
          type    : COUNTER_DOUBLE_ASYNC,
          payload : getState().counter
        })
        resolve()
      }, 200)
    })
  }
};
```

I'm impressive because why only setting up one line middleware Thunk for redux, Redux can automatically create dispatch object when calling above method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question, can you be more precise please ? If you want to know how redux-thunk is implemented : https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding how redux middleware works you can read this doc: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Let's say that we have such redux store initialization (from http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html):

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'

let todoApp = combineReducers(reducers)
let store = createStore(
  todoApp,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
)
```

And there is a naïve implementation of applyMiddleware (from http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html):

```js
// Warning: Naïve implementation!
// That's *not* Redux API.

function applyMiddleware(store, middlewares) {
  middlewares = middlewares.slice()
  middlewares.reverse()

  let dispatch = store.dispatch
  middlewares.forEach(middleware =>
    dispatch = middleware(store)(dispatch)
  )

  return Object.assign({}, store, { dispatch })
}
```

It's not the version in redux, but for general understanding.
Also, it doesn't have `store` parameter itself in redux.

As you see, the main idea that on every action a middleware receives object with  `dispatch` and `getState` properties.

The `thunkMiddleware` itself is very simple. There is a little simplified version than in sources:

```js
let thunkMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    return action(dispatch, getState);
  }

  return next(action);
}
```

For `typeof action === 'function'` it runs this `action` with `dispatch` and `getState` parameters, which can be used later for dispatching other actions in thunks. And it is how thunks work.

Comment: thanks for nice post about how thunk works :D I have read source code of thunk, really short and understandable but I don't know how react's middleware is worked at that time.